# How to synchronize SQLite database with SQL Server in xamarin?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, database-replication

I am in the process of developing an app for picking up orders for billing, in which I have determined that it works offline because users arrive at certain places where there is no signal, therefore the app will work with a local database SQLite, which I want when it connects to the internet, it synchronizes the data in a bidirectional way, it is a MERGE type replica, between SQL Server and SQLite, it should be noted that the app works in Xamarin Forms, I wanted to know if there is any information about this.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: this is potentially a complex problem and there is no easy prebaked solution.  It depends on your remote db, your requirements, your data, etc

Answer (score 0):

It's a manual process, you read from your SQLite db and write in SQL Server and vis versa, keep track of the data you already synced using flags and date columns. ( By manual I mean Write Code)

Comment: I assumed something like that, but you have a post, blog or something like that about how to give me the idea, honestly it's something new and maybe you want to run before walking, but to give me ideas on this issue. Thank you again for your attention and support. Mourad GHERSA

Comment: where are you stuck ? did you manage to bring your data from SQL Server to your Xamarin app and write back to your database  ? did you manage to read write data from an SQLite Db ? the last thing to do is matching your data.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i working the project same as you, using [Dotmim.sync](https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/Web.html#overview) tool

for data around 10k to sync with no problem but after 100k data it need take time to sync, maybe that sync tool will help you